# External database to oracle fusion

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

Is it possible to upload an external database into oracle fusion and how? For example I have an excel file that contains data then I want it to upload in oracle fusion then I can use it to create an BI Report. Thanks!

Comment: Oracle Fusion is a suite of middleware apps. Do you mean you want to load data from an Excel spreadsheet into a database table which you can use in a report?

Comment: Yes. But I can used it in a future used. Like I can used it as a table?

Comment: Sounds like you should read about External Tables. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E)